# While-language interpreter OCaml

Tags: ocaml, interpreter

Probably this question is really easy, but I'm a beginner of the Ocaml programming language. I've found on the web an interpreter written in Ocaml for the WHILE-language. To be more precise I've 5 .ml files implementing:

- Main;
- Semantics;
- Types;
- Type-checker;
- Data-flow-analysis;

How do I use these files? For instance if I wanna run a program written in the WHILE-language what I've to do?

I have tried to compile (ocamlc -c file.ml) the files I have but unsuccessfully.

I'm working on ubuntu with the ocaml package installed.

Comment: You can try `ocamlbuild Main.byte`, if things are simple enough it can work. Then you run it `./Main.byte`

Comment: How do you expect people to help you if you don't provide correct information ? Would it be difficult to provide a link to where you found the sources (or it is homework ?). What the file list is ? `ls`

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend first making sure that you can compile a very simple OCaml file, like this:

```
$ cat tiny.ml
let () = Printf.printf "hello, world\n"
$ ocamlc -o tiny tiny.ml
$ tiny
hello, world
$
```

If this works, the next question is whether the 5 files you found on the net are actually a well formed collection of OCaml modules.  If they are, then you need to compile them *in the correct order* (in order of dependency).  If the correct order is a, b, c, d, e, then you should be able to say:

```
$ ocamlc -o whileinterp a.ml b.ml c.ml d.ml e.ml
```

To identify the order, I'd actually consult wherever you got the files from.  There are 120 different possible orders!  If this is impossible, you can deduce it from the module dependencies.